# Bitlocker, or other full-disk encryption (FDE), on Windows 8.1 To Go

Tags: windows-8.1, bitlocker, bootable-media, disk-encryption, windows-to-go

I am currently running Windows 8.1 (Pro) To Go on a 256 GB Samsung T3 flash drive and I am wanting to enable Bitlocker, or any FDE/WDE solution, on it.

Currently it is able to boot from a 500 MB EFI partition, or a legacy BIOS-boot configuration. Every time I attempt to enable Bitlocker, the pre-encryption test (verifying system requirements) fails with:

> Changes made to your computer require that you restart before running Bitlocker Setup

I have enabled "Allow Bitlocker without a compatible TPM" in the registry.  This has persisted over 4+ reboots.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you restarted the computer?

Comment: To be explicit: OMG...yes...

Comment: Any ideas what would be changing in the file system on boot that is annoying Bitlocker?

Comment: Maybe, UEFI might have secureboot enabled. which means that bitlocker will check to see each time whether or not some parts of the computer are the same. But since you have windows to go, there is no "computer". The drive could be mounted under a different letter each time all together. That would be the first place I look. Group policy, anything related to secure boot. Side note though, You might have better luck going into another OS you can boot into and encrypting the drive as a removable media instead of a system drive. Not sure if this will even work, never tried it, but worth a shot.

Comment: Or you could always use a different encryption method, like veracrypt for FDE

Comment: Security policy at work would prefer Bitlocker (which is a shame) so I'd like to dip a toe a bit deeper into this rabbithole before I try something else.

The drive is assigned C: and secure boot, paging and hibernation files are disabled